New Ubuntu 24.04 install no sound from MacMini
New Ubuntu user just installed 24.04 and getting no sound on a 2015 MacMini intel core i7 8700b x12. I've got Dummy output under sound settings
Is there a command to identify a sound card, and a command to load a sound card?

You need to add some details to have a good chance of getting a useful answer. Minimum hardware details (which mac mini, year, arch etc) and output of lspci and/or dmesg (any audio related log output)

check out https://t2linux.org/
